# Higher order proxy abuse

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Javascript is claimed to be a functional language, but it certainly doesn't feel like one. It lacks most of the things that make functional languages neat, one of those things being point free style. 
Fortunately we got arrow functions and proxies in ES6, so I took it upon myself to implement point free style with proxies:

```
let pfree = ctx => f => new Proxy (f, {
  has: (t, p) => p in t || p in ctx
, get: (t, p) => {
    let k = p in t? t[p]: ctx[p];

    if (k instanceof Function) return (
      function fetch (_k) {
        return pfree (ctx) ( x => ( q => q instanceof Function
                                       ? fetch (q)
                                       : t (q)
                                  ) ( _k(x) )
                           )
      })(k);

    return k;
  }
});
```

Quite the headace, but it does the job- in nodejs you can use it like this:

```
let p = pfree (global) (x => x)

with (p) {
  add  = x => y => x + y
  succ = add (1)
  five = succ . add (2) . succ (1)
}

console.log(five) // 5
```

The problem arise when you make higher order functions:

```
with (p) {
  flip  = f => x => y => f (y) (x)
  Const = a => b => a
  dot   = f => a => b => f(a(b))
  ap    = f => g => x => f (x) (g (x))

  zero  = flip (Const)
  succ  = ap (dot) 

  num   = n => n (x => x + 1) (0) // The number n is represented by running a function n times over some input

  console.log ( num ( succ ( succ ( succ (zero) )))) // 3
  console.log ( num . succ . succ . succ (zero) )    // [Function]
}
```

And I can't really wrap my head around why ..

ideas?

Comment: Notice that you can use point-free style even without the dot for composition :-)

Comment: @Bergi `dot(succ)(dot(succ)(succ))` doesn't quite feel the same as `succ . succ . succ`

Comment: Sure, but it has the advantage of being usable JavaScript, not proxy abuse :-) I love these thought experiments, but for real usage you'd rather compile Haskell to JS.

Comment: Javascript is claimed to be a multi paradigm language. If you love the succinct Haskell syntax, well, code Haskell or create another compile-to-javascript language.

Comment: @LUH3417 Obviusly I wouldn't actually use this out in the wild, I'm simply playing around with javascript, finding out how far I can push its limits with the new ES6 features.

Comment: OK and don't get me wrong, I'd love it if we had custom infix, first class operators in Javascript.

Comment: LUH3417 Pssst- take this- you didn't hear it from me: http://www.2ality.com/2011/12/fake-operator-overloading.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is simple:

```
succ . add(2)
```

is indistinguishable from

```
(succ . add) (2)
```

with the rules of JavaScript property access, but you expect them to do a different thing.

The solution is impossible (I dare say), but you might be able to work around by introducing a custom grouping operator:

```
group(succ . add) (2)
```

which you also should invoke on assignment to a property of `p`. You should be able to make the following work:

```
addFour = succ . add (2) . succ
five = group(succ . add (2) . succ) (1)
fiveAgain = addFour (1)

console.log ( group(num . succ . succ . succ) (zero) )    // 3
```